# qgis 2.8.1 - processing gdal 1.11.2 error (mac, 10.10.2)

Tags: qgis, gdal, mac

i've just recently installed qgis 2.8.1 on my mac.
including all relevant packages from kyngchaos - i.e. GDAL Complete 1.11 framework package, Matplotlib Python module, numpy - and updated python to 2.7.9

did some testing and was pretty happy with the new 2.8.1

when i tried to run gdal/ogr geoalgorithms from processing toolbox qgis returned the following  error:
"GDAL command output: /bin/sh: xxx: command not found"
... where xxx is the name of the command.

same problem with any tested command !

i've already been searching for that kind of issue for a while but didn't find anything that could solve the problem. most promising was an article about inserting /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages - path into sys.path ... but nothing changed.