# QGIS just installed on MAC OSX - vector layer styles do not work properly

Tags: symbology, mac, qgis-2.10

I am a newbie with QGIS - I have just installed QGIS 2.10.1-Pisa. I am following a youtube tutorial by Steven Bernard and I just found that the styles do not work properly (I run Mac OS X Lion 7.5.1. on a 1.7 GHz Intel Core i5 MacBook Air).

When I want to change the sybology of my map, this does not work properly. If you have a look at step 3.2.3. Changing Symbol Structure in the manual on [3.2.1. basic Follow Along: Changing Colors](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html) , QGIS does not provide me with any choices. It tells me that 'This layer doesn't have any editable properties'. I am attaching a screenshot just to be clear.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I got the exact same problem. And I don't think a downgrade to 2.8 is a solution ...

I have tried to uninstal maptolib and re-install it without any change.

Any other good idea on this?

Comment: I still got same problem with 2.14.3 !

Comment: Same problem now with the QGIS 2.14.x and 2.18.X on MAC OS 10.8.5
Works well on MAC OS 10.9.5
It seems to be a problem of compatibility?
So the other solution instead of degrading QGIS would be to upgrade MacOSX to at least 10.9.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar error with pseudocolor properties on macboook air mid 2011 OS x 10.10.4

This solved my problem:

- updated matplotlib using terminal (sudo pip install --upgrade mathplotlib)
- reinstalled QGIS 2.8 Wien instead of QGIS 2.10 (http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)

Comment: And yes, QGIS 2.8 works fine!

Comment: Could you elaborate as to how matplotlib is relevant for this solution? Is it not enough to downgrade to 2.8?

Comment: The example from @BritH appears to be a vector layer, and not a raster layer.  I'm running **QGIS Pisa 2.10.1** on **Yosemite 10.10.4** and am able to stylize vector layers.   (However, I am not able to stylize raster layers though due to a known issue, detailed more [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156324/unable-to-stylize-as-pseudocolor-render-type-on-mac-osx/157911#157911), and reported as an official issue [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13162).)