# qgis 2.10.1. mac - geotiff singleband pseudocolor

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, mac, rendering

i've installed mac version from kyngchaos including all required packages ...
... and just noticed the following:

while windows version behaves like expected when trying to render an ordinary tif via "singleband pseudocolor" (see the image)
[image: qgis 2.10-win]

the same procedure on the current mac-release returns:
[image: qgis 2.10-mac]

interesting detail: pressing "apply" in mac version doesnt change anything and if you press "OK" and re-open layer properties the "render type"-setting has  swiched back to "singleband grey".

even more interesting: "singleband grey" is faulty too:
none of the options "color gradient", "min", "max", "contrast enhancement" does affect the way the tif is displayed, 
neither do the "load min/max values" settings !

anyone any ideas?

Comment: It's a [bug, reported already](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13162) - good idea to keep the old versions around as well when QGIS updates.

Comment: thx for information - but i didn't find anything about the singleband grey problem in mac version (Mac OSX Yosemite)

Comment: concernig duplicate mark  ...

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156324/unable-to-stylize-as-pseudocolor-render-type-on-mac-osx ... just deals with sinlgeband pseudocolor !   ... on my osx 10.10.4. "singleband grey" option seems to be faulty too. but there is no open ticket on http://hub.qgis.org/issues/ for "singleband gray"

Comment: just noticed the update on http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13162: "... any change to the layer properties made in the "Layer Properties" are not applied ... " and the conclusio (ibid.)  "... this makes 2.10 unusable for me :( ..."

Answer (score 1):

from this topic: [QGIS just installed on MAC OSX - vector layer styles do not work properly](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157471/qgis-just-installed-styles-do-not-work-properly/157488#157488)

> I had a similar error with pseudocolor properties on macboook air mid
>   2011 OS x 10.10.4
>
> This solved my problem:

```
updated matplotlib using terminal
reinstalled QGIS 2.8 Wien instead of QGIS 2.10 (http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)
```

Comment: just tried steps 3.2.1 - 3.2.4 on mac osx 10.10.4 macbookpro mid 2011 without any problem. any kind of vector-data style operation seem to work properly. did an update of any relevant package (kyngchaos) before qgis install ... my problem seems to affect just raster-data